# How to prevent button from animating when clicked

Tags: ios, animation, button, swiftui

I'm trying to prevent a button from animating when clicked, but I have not been successful.

I've tried setting `UIButton.appearance().isHighlighted`, `.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted` and `.showsTouchWhenHiglighted`, to `false`. I've also tried:

```
Button(action: {}) {
   Text("X")
}
.animation(.none)
```

Comment: Check out my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61593453/disable-default-button-click-animation-in-swiftui/77099827#77099827

Answer (score 5):

I think the purest solution to this problem will be not using `Button`.
Instead you can do it like this:

```swift
Text("X")
  .onTapGesture {
    print("clicked!")
  }
```

Comment: I need to use a button.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to disable it is to provide a custom primitive button style that does not include the default tap animation. Here is the code to accomplish this:

```
struct NoTapAnimationStyle: PrimitiveButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            // Make the whole button surface tappable. Without this only content in the label is tappable and not whitespace. Order is important so add it before the tap gesture
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .onTapGesture(perform: configuration.trigger)
    }
}
```

Then apply it with this modifier on the button:

```
.buttonStyle(NoTapAnimationStyle())
```

Repost of answer here: [Disable default button click animation in SwiftUi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61593453/disable-default-button-click-animation-in-swiftui/77099827#77099827)

Comment: Great solution! Just be aware: This solution will change the default label color from blue to white.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't get it to work any other way you can disable the button and attach a tap gesture recognizer to it.

Answer (score 1):

Almost, to disable animation in some place we should set `nil`, like

```
Button(action: {}) {
   Text("X")
}
.animation(nil)     // << here !!
```

Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

Comment: I'm using the same environment, but it only works on the first click. After that, the animation returns.

Comment: .animation(nil) is now deprecated.