# SwiftUI button unintended animations

Tags: swiftui

---

***tl;dr:***

Default system animation used when pressing a SwiftUI button, even if I have specified another animation (or no animation at all)

---

I am having some strange animation issues with SwiftUI.

I have reduced the issue to the smallest reproducible example:

```swift
struct MyCirclePlaygroundView: View {
    @State var isCircleBig: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MyCircle(isBig: $isCircleBig)

            Text("Toggle")
                .onTapGesture { isCircleBig.toggle() }
        }
    }
}


struct MyCircle: View {
    @Binding var isBig: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Button { isBig.toggle() }
        label: { Circle() }
        .frame(width: isBig ? 150 : 100, height: isBig ? 150 : 100)
    }
}
```

[image]

If I toggle the `isBig` via the "Toggle" text tap, things work as expected, the circle becomes big, there are no animations.
If I tap on the circle itself, I get an unexpected animation of the state change.
Notice I have not put `withAnimation` or `.animation(..., value: ...)` anywhere.

Furthermore, if I want to add an animation to my circle by doing either:

```
.onTapGesture {
    withAnimation(.bouncy(duration: 2)) {
        isCircleBig.toggle()
    }
}
```

or

```
MyCircle(isBig: $isCircleBig)
    .animation(.bouncy(duration: 2), value: isCircleBig)
```

The specified animation (and duration) only gets respected when I toggle externally - if I press on the button, the default system animation is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial an error I have discovered this is an odd combination of circumstances around the SwiftUI button system. It seems the built-in SwiftUI button animation (on touch down / up) cause unexpected other animations.

Here are my findings (+ some solutions):

(All of these apply to the `MyCircle` code)

- If instead of a `Button` we use something else, things work. (in our case for example `Circle().onTapGesture { isBig.toggle() }`).
- If the change of size is done via a `scaleEffect` instead of changing the frame, things work. Note that this `scaleEffect` has to be applied to the whole `Button`, not only to it's `label` view, otherwise even with a `scaleEffect` it does not work.
- If we wrap the `isBig.toggle()` (inside `MyCircle`) in a `withAnimation { }` - things work. And the 'parent' animation style propagates correctly. However if no animation was intended, this does not work, because it would animate. An alternative to this is to use `withAnimation(.none) { }` which works, but it does a bit confusing to a reader, because it actually still animates with the parent animation (probably a good idea to add a comment explaining it).

None of the solutions is ideal, but they avoid confusing and conflicting animations.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent the animation by applying `.animation(.none)` to the binding that you pass to `MyCircle`:

```swift
MyCircle(isBig: $isCircleBig.animation(.none))
```

Alternatively, you can apply your preferred animation instead:

```swift
MyCircle(isBig: $isCircleBig.animation(.bouncy(duration: 2)))
```

*EDIT* If you don't like having to add an additional animation definition, but you still want `MyCircle` to contain a `Button`, then another way to suppress the animation is to use `withAnimation(.none)` inside the button callback:

```swift
Button {
    withAnimation(.none) {
        isBig.toggle()
    }
} label: {
    Circle()
}
.frame(width: isBig ? 150 : 100, height: isBig ? 150 : 100)
```

With the animation disabled, you still see a bit of an opacity effect, but this is the effect for a button press. If you take off the size change then you'll see that the effect still happens. Also, when you specficy a preferred animation, the duration of the button-press effect is independent of the animation you specify.

To disable the button-press effect too, see [Disable default button click animation in SwiftUi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61593453/20386264).

Comment: Thanks, these solutions work, but it does mean one more animation definition is required (and one has to remember to maintain it). Ideally there would be a way to just "respect" whatever animation is defined at the higher level (or none), the way SwiftUI usually works. The link to the other answer is useful, thanks.

Comment: @NikolaySuvandzhiev OK, answer updated with another way to suppress the animation. Of course, not using a `Button` would also avoid the issue.